# How to fill properly a buffer?

Tags: python, types, buffer

I'm communicating with a parrot drone (jumping sumo) with python, and I need to send him a buffer every 25ms to maintain connection. Problem, I don't know how to do that ^^

Inspired by this code, written in javascript: https://github.com/forgeByAcision/node-sumo/blob/master/lib/sumo.js
I tried to translate that:

```
var buf = new Buffer(7);

buf.writeUInt8(constants.ARCOMMANDS_ID_PROJECT_JUMPINGSUMO, 0);
buf.writeUInt8(constants.ARCOMMANDS_ID_JUMPINGSUMO_CLASS_PILOTING, 1);
buf.writeUInt16LE(constants.ARCOMMANDS_ID_JUMPINGSUMO_PILOTING_CMD_PCMD, 2);
buf.writeUInt8(this._pcmd.flag || 1, 4);
buf.writeInt8(this._pcmd.speed || 0, 5);
buf.writeInt8(this._pcmd.turn || 0, 6);
```

I heard about struct library, but I'm stuck.
How to write such types, how to change the byte order only for a variable ?

PS: I'm not stuck with sockets (well, I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `struct` to pack your data into the buffer. Something like:

```
from struct import *
buf = ['\0'] * 7

pack_into('BBHBbb', buf, 0, constants.ARCOMMANDS_ID_PROJECT_JUMPINGSUMO, constants.ARCOMMANDS_ID_JUMPINGSUMO_CLASS_PILOTING, constants.ARCOMMANDS_ID_JUMPINGSUMO_PILOTING_CMD_PCMD,...)
```

The format string can also have an initial character that indicates the byte order. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment).

Comment: Thanks you solved one of my problems, I mixed bytes and bits ^^ But buf initialization doesn't work for me with ['\0] * 7, pack_into tells me he wants a byte-like object

Comment: Oops, probably need `buf = bytearray(7)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used struct module to pack my data in a buffer like this:

```
import struct

buf = struct.pack("BBHBbb", constant1, constant2, constant3, constant4 ....)
```